# Can I build a DApp using Hyperledger?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ethereum, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-sawtooth

I want to build a DApp. Is it possible to build it using Hyperledger Frameworks? If yes, how is it different from a DApp built using Ethereum?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three projects within Hyperledger that will support EVM based smart contracts. Hyperledger [Burrow](https://github.com/hyperledger/burrow), which is the descendant of ErisDB implements an EVM conforming to the Ethereum specification, that uses Tendermint for consensus and is increasingly being componentized such that its EVM can be used as a library in other projects.

Hyperledger [Seth](https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-seth) is the first integration of Hyperledger Burrow's EVM into the Sawtooth platform.

Hyperledger [Fabric](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-evm) is also undergoing a project to integrate the Burrow EVM, though presently awaiting a refactor of the Burrow library to be merged.

The process of developing Dapps should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @christoferris. How much does it cost to build a DApp in hyperledger, I mean how much one has to pay for the nodes/users?

Comment: It costs nothing

Comment: So, how is it de-centralized?
Suppose, I build a DApp using Hyperledger Fabric and I wrote the contract in chaincode, then how will I let users install my app and use it?
What all should I do after creating business network card?

Comment: It would run in a Fabric, Sawtooth or Burrow network hosted by you or another provider. It is not fully decentralized in the same way that permission-less Ethereum network operates, because these platforms all use non-POW consensus.

Comment: @christo4ferris How do you compare with some non-POW systems like EOS?

Comment: I haven't studied EOS in depth, but Fabric is not based on crypto-currency -- at all. You can create tokens, and one could implement a cryptocurrency, but it does not require mining or any fee structure to pay for processing. Hyperledger Fabric along with the other Hyperledger projects aim to implement permissioned blickchain platforms... very different from public, permissionless platforms.